serverless function seems to be not invoking on vercel rather statuc assets are shown on dashboard
So my application is Node, Express, GraphQL and MongoDB and is written in TS.
I'm triggering the vercel deployment using a github action. The deployment seems to working fine but it is not getting the serverless function to run.
Entry point of my application is src/server.ts
and in the build it is dist/src/server.js
But on the vercel dashboard it is not picking the serverless function but showing statis assets.
My vercel.json file
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
        "src": "dist/src/server.js",
        "use": "@vercel/node",
        "config": { "includeFiles": ["dist/**"] }
    }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "dist/src/server.js"
        }
    ]
}

and my src/server.ts is attached as a file
//imports here

//some TS interfaces here

function createServer(): ServerSetup {
  const app = express() // Express server

  // * Middlewares here
 

  const expressServer = http.createServer(app)

  const apolloServer = new ApolloServer<CustomContext>({
    typeDefs: typeDefs,
    resolvers: resolvers,
    cache: 'bounded',
  })

  return { app, expressServer, apolloServer }
}

async function startServer() {
  const { app, expressServer, apolloServer } = createServer()

  await connectDatabase()

  // * Start Apollo servers
  await apolloServer.start()

  // * Apply middleware after the servers have started
  // app.get('/', (_, res: Response) => {
  //   const routes = [process.env.BASE_URL + ':' + PORT + '/public', process.env.BASE_URL + ':' + PORT + '/protected']

  //   res.status(200).send(`<p>Server is up and running</p> <br> ${routes.map((el) => `<p>Route to <a href="${el}">${el}</a></p>`)} `)
  // })

  app.use(
    '/graphql',
    authMiddleware,
    expressMiddleware(apolloServer, {
      context: async ({ req, res }: { req: CustomRequest; res: Response }) => ({
        req,
        res,
        user: req.user,
      }),
    }),
  )

  expressServer.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`[ server] Server is running at http://localhost:${PORT}`)
  })

  const socketServer = new SocketServer(expressServer)
  console.log('[ socket] SocketServer has been started.')

  return { expressServer, socketServer }
}

export { createServer, startServer }

startServer()

export default startServer

